# PHP MySQL cant read data from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

The dropdown list is not showing the data that i input in the database

```
Product Category:
<select name="product_cat">
    <option>Select a Category</option>
    <?php 
    $get_cats = "select * from categories";
    $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);
    while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
        $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
        $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
        echo "<option>$cat_title</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: are you getting $cat_title now? if so change it to echo "<option>.$cat_title.</option>";

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
<select name="product_cat">
   <option value="">Select a Category</option>
   <?php 
      $get_cats = "select * from categories";
      $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);
      while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
        //$cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];     // no need to put in another variable
        //$cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];    // no need to put in another variable
        echo "<option value='".$row_cats['cat_id']."'>".$row_cats['cat_title']."</option>";
      }
   ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Are the removed variables only change? It should work in original way too, and I think it is more readable.

Comment: If you want then you will assign new variables as you did. But this is time and space consuming. @TuomasK

Comment: But it doesn't affect the output in any way. So this doesn't solve the problem. @SHAZ

Comment: try to `var_dump($row_cats);` see what exactly you get.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change your while loop from this:

```
while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
```

To this:

```
while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_row($run_cats)){
```

`mysqli_fetch_array()` returns all rows of the table in an array. You would need to store it in a variable and make a foreach loop.

`mysqli_fetch_row()` returns only one row at a time. It also returns `false` if all rows are already fetched, so you can use it in a while loop, like you did.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for='product_cat'>Product Category:
    <select name='product_cat'>
        <optgroup label='Select a Category'>
            <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled' hidden='hidden'>Select a Category
            <?php 
                $sql='select * from `categories`';
                $res=mysqli_query( $con, $sql );
                if( $res ){
                    while( $rs=mysqli_fetch_object( $res ) ){
                        echo "<option value='{$rs->cat_id}'>{$rs->cat_title}";
                    }
                }
                mysqli_free_result( $res );
                $con->close();
            ?>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
    Product Category:
    <?php $get_cats="SELECT * FROM categories"; $run_cats=mysqli_query($con,$get_cats);?>
    <select name="product_cat">
        <option>Select a Category</option>
        <?php while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_cats)){?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_cats['cat_id'];?>"><?php echo $row_cats['cat_title']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</html>
```